# Not able to fetch JSON data in iOS

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdata

I will post my code here:

NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?limit=25"];

```
NSLog(@"string:%@",string);

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:string];

NSLog(@"url %@",url);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSLog(@"data:%@",data);

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetcheddata:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

-(void)fetcheddata:(NSData *){}

The above code worked for me earlier. I don't know what happened it's not working now. When I pasted the URL in the browser it is working. Please guide me in this case. It shows me data parameter is nil and exception is NSInvalidArgumentException.

Comment: Your code works for me, I always get data after like 3 seconds.

Comment: I created new project and wrote the code again in viewdidload but still it doesn't work for me. I am using Xcode 6 iOS8.

Comment: I am also use Xcode 6 and iOS 8, can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
```

with

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

Comment: it is still not working. I appreciate your help. I think it is not because of dispatch_async line of code.

Comment: i think you need to paste your complete url code inside dispatch_synch. Please try like this

Comment: By the way what is the difference between yours dispatch_async and mine?

Comment: Well, I heard when anyone is trying to get the data from web services, it is recommended not to go for main thread. If one uses main thread when a lot of data is there to get it, then the app won't respond for some time till it gets the data. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes it is correct but if you are updating the same in ui then it should be in the main thread. if not, then your code is good.